# How to detect if a postgresql gin index is bloated

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

For btree indices, the `pgstattuple` extension provides the `avg_leaf_density` in `pgstatindex` to assess the 'bloatedness' of an index, i.e. the approximate ratio of the current size and the size it would have after a reindex.

The `pgstattuple` extension provides a `pgstatginindex` function, but neither of the returned values seem to be relevant to 'bloatedness'.

Is there a somewhat quick way to detect if a reindex would be useful?

Comment: So far I could not find anything.  One way might be creating the same index (using `CONCURRENTLY`) and comparing the sizes.  If the new one is smaller than the other, you can just drop the old one (`CONCURRENTLY`, of course).

Comment: In the end, I may end up doing a VACUUM FULL at weekends, and hope the indices do not get too much bloated during the week.

Comment: Well, if you have the luxury of doing it, then why not :)  Building the indexes the way I suggested is better for systems that must stay up constantly, and might use up less disk space.  Not to mention you'll have an idea of the bloat :)